# How to estimate the right size furnace for my house

Tags: furnace

I estimated the BTU for a new furnace for my house to be around 62,000 BTU. My Trane XR 90 furnace is 80,000 BTU. The square footage of my house is 1040 sq ft. Is a furnace over 18,000 BTU overkill for my house?
Also 3 companies in town stock Lennox parts. Just wondered how the Armstrong Air-A951 furnaces rate.
And are they hard to get parts for?

Comment: How did you estimate? What are the insulation levels in all the parts of your house? What climate is your house in? Those things are needed to make an accurate estimate, though there are plenty of (bad) Rule of Thumb estimates that may not apply well depending on how your particular house is built and insulated. I get by fine on less than 30K BTU for more than 2000 square feet, in a climate with -5 to -20 °F design temps depending who you ask, but I am also very well insulated. If you can improve your insulation you can also reduce the size of your furnace...

Comment: I used an online calculator. The attic has blown in insulation-R30.Exterior walls R12.Ontario, Canada .The weather has been between -30- -40 C this week.In 2 mths l had to get the frost cleaned out of my intake pipe on my roof.I was told l could vent the pvc pipes through the wall instead. But l would have to get a pro to decide if that change in pipe direction would meet code.

Comment: There are lots of heat loss calculators out there. I don't have familiarity with any so no recommendations from me. But for a heat-only furnace, some over-kill isn't going to create any problems.   Nice to be able to warm up your house quickly when coming back from vacation or a stay away.   It's much worse to have an A/C unit oversized because it doesn't run long enough to remove moisture from the air, leaving you with a "clammy" feeling.

Comment: The furnace runs fine now.Its 14 years old. In the last 2 years l got a new ignition module (old one had a black mark caused by the elect .furnace cleaner),new inducer and fan motor.Tired of soaking more money into it.

Comment: Opinion: those are *pathetic* insulation values for anyplace where -40 is on the menu. Unfortunately *not atypical for an older house,* but still pathetic. If the calculator did not also require input about windows, doors, basement, it can't possibly provide a complete and accurate picture of BTU/hr use. Less than 200 square feet of (good quality low-e) windows use more heat than 1000 square feet of ceiling, in my case. Bad windows could easily be 4 times worse... An oversized furnace does have standby losses when it's not running, which are worse than those of a right-sized furnace.

Comment: A proper answer to this will require what's called a "Manual J" calculation. Anything else is just guesswork (even if it's educated guesswork). This calculation will take into account the size of your house, the thickness of the walls, what type of windows you have, what type of insulation you have, what type of siding you have, what direction your house is facing, what climate zone your house is in, etc. After this calculation is done for the whole house, you can do a Manual S calculation that will determine what HVAC equipment you need.

Comment: And 60,000 BTUs is enough for a *2,000* sq ft house if it is properly insulated and ventilated. When was your house built? Newer houses will typically need less than older houses.

Comment: The house was built in 1972.

Comment: If your furnace produces 80k BTU and you need 62k BTU, then you've only overprovisioned by 18k BTU, not 60K BTU. Also, I removed the 2nd question: A) Two questions makes it "too broad", B) What your local suppliers stock is irrelevant to the question at hand, and C) "what do you think" is entirely opinion based and explicitly off topic for [diy.se].

Comment: Your furnace should not be sized based on normal use or average temperatures. It should be based on the extreme temperatures.

Comment: Having installed many systems I agree with lee, you size the furnace for the worst week. Heat pumps do not do well with extreme cold so this is where over sizing may not be enough on really cold periods.

Comment: +1 To TylerH Always ask your HVAC sales rep for a Manual J calculation. They should be doing one anyways if they’re trying to sell you a furnace or air conditioner, and if they aren’t, they shouldn’t be quoting you on a new HVAC system.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot estimate a furnace by the size of your house.   That is just a factor in the equation, and it is not 80% of the equation or even half.

So first when you have the size of your house you should not calculate square feet, it should be cubic feet.   A house with 8 foot ceilings is considerably smaller than ones with 10-12 feet ceilings.   If a furnace tech quotes you on the square feet in your house - wow get a new tech.

Also you need to factor in the cubic area of the unfinished areas that are connected - your basement, useable attic space, an enclosed patio.

Then you have to guestimate - there are services that will get this done for you accurately - how efficient you are insulating your house.   A house that is well insulated may require half the heating of a house with little to no insulation and bad windows/doors.

The last thing is the one-offs.   Are your duct runs longer than average?   Do your ducts travel in the attic or underneath foundation?   Do you have more ducts than normal for a house of your size?

You are rating the entire house system plus size.   There is no easy equation.   An old exterior door with gaps in the middle of the house could cause 10% heat loss.   The problem is if you rate too low your house will never be warm and you will stress the furnace and blower and it won't last as long.   Yes rating too high and you lose a little money in efficiency.   But really you always have to be a little over when estimating or willing to spend a lot of money insulating and replacing windows/doors.